# SQL Roundup to 2 or 3 decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL only have round to nearest function and roundup to nearest number.
How can I round up my prices, if price <1 roundup to 3 decimal and if price >=1 roundup to 2 decimal.
E.g
Price

```
$0.0024 round up to 0.003
$0.0051 round up to 0.06
$1.213  round up to 1.22
```

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info , what is your DBMS ?

Comment: Sorry for typo, 0.0051 will be roundup to 0.006

Comment: Hi Daniel, I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2014

Comment: So it's always a round up and not down ? 0.0051 should be 0.005 if it's round down.

Comment: What about negative numbers?

Comment: @jarlh for a price ?

Comment: @DanielE., refunds, price changes - what do I know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ceiling()` to always round up:

```
select case when price < 1 then ceiling(price * 1000) / 1000
                           else ceiling(price * 100) / 100
       end
from table
```

Comment: Thanks so much Jarlh.. Works perfectly!!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `round` function with case below will work for sql server

```
select case when price<1 then  round(price,3) else round(price,2) end
from table
```

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 things to know :

`ROUND()` Always round **DOWN** :

```
ROUND(0.051, 2) = 0.05
```

If you want to round up, you need to use another function : [`CEILING()`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_ceiling.asp)
But Ceiling only return an integer. The tricks is to do this :

```
CEILING(0.0051 * 1000)/1000 = 0.006
```

For the data you provide here is the solution :

```
SELECT 
      CASE
         WHEN price < 1 THEN CEILING(price*1000)/1000
         ELSE CEILING(price*100)/100
      END AS rounded_price_up
FROM mytable
```